# how to stop python loop from stacking information

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, python-docx

I plan to automate in python something that will create several .docx files using a while loop. Each file will have its own unique name and have some information inside of it. My problem is that when looping, the information I get inside the documents is stacking.

I believe there is a simple solution out there, I just can't seem to find it.

Here is the block of code:

```
i=1
while i < 10:
    os.chdir("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\" +FolderName)
    doc.save(str(doc_number[i])+str(essay_type[i])+' '+str(titles[i])+' '+str(writer[i])+'.docx');
    doc.add_paragraph('Title/Keyword:'+str(titles[i]));
    doc.add_paragraph('Reasech Link:'+str(link[i]));
    doc.add_paragraph('Target Site:'+str(keyword[i]));
    doc.save(str(doc_number[i])+str(essay_type[i])+' '+str(titles[i])+' '+str(writer[i])+'.docx');
    i+=2
```

[This is the first document. I would like every document to have an output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t12WS.png)

[This is the last document created, as you can see the information from the first document as well as the next 3 documents are all stacked and shown in the final output of this last document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O3Dx.png)

Comment: You are not redefining `doc` inside the `while` loop so presumably it's all going to be written to the same document object. I assume you need something like `doc = Document()` just after `os.chdir("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\" +FolderName)` and pass it a new file name

Comment: Can you please show the output inside the question and explain what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: I haven't used `docx` but I'm not sure there is a way of clearing a document object that I can see in the documentation, so it looks like you just have to keep making new objects to stop all the paragraphs being accumulated.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts done

Comment: @roganjosh  yes that was what I wanted to do, thanks. however is there a way to do it without wasting too many lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange your code like this:

```
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\" +FolderName)
i=1
while i < 10:
    doc = Document()
    doc.add_paragraph('Title/Keyword:'+str(titles[i]));
    doc.add_paragraph('Research Link:'+str(link[i]));
    doc.add_paragraph('Target Site:'+str(keyword[i]));
    doc.save(str(doc_number[i])+str(essay_type[i])+' '+str(titles[i])+' '+str(writer[i])+'.docx');
    i+=2
```